# Meta tags in header in RStudio markdown

Tags: r, rstudio

This question has been asked but no easy solution has been posted previously.

Is there a a way of inserting a meta tag in the header of an html file produced from R markdown in RStudio with RStudio's native knitHTML method? I need a refresh tag.